# Querying of off a query MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I'be been googling around about nested queries but can't find anything that I can grasp about how to go about this particular operation.

First, I'll show you my DB schema

```
CREATE TABLE slsemp
(   empID   char(4) NOT NULL,
empname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
prtime  enum('yes','no') NOT NULL,   # we can only accept yes or no values to the part-time employee indicator
RegionID char(2)    NOT NULL,               # enums are often used for boolean values in a BD
PosID char(4) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (empID),
FOREIGN KEY (regionID) REFERENCES region (RegionID),
FOREIGN KEY (PosID) REFERENCES slspos(PosID));


# create the sales transactions table
CREATE TABLE  slstranx
(   tranxID int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, #starts at a certain number, then increments accordingly
empID char(4) NOT NULL,
ProdID char(3) NOT NULL,
Qty int(5)  NOT NULL,
Unitprice Decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,   # please note we are capturing the unit price at the transactional level in this case
SAmt    Float(10,2), #store up to 10 (TOTAL?) with 2 digits past decimal point
SalesDate date, # 'date' data type is organized as follows YYYYMMDD. You need to make sure that raw data contains the DATE in the YYYYMMDD format
                # For example 20150915
PRIMARY KEY (tranxID),
FOREIGN KEY (ProdID) REFERENCES product (ProdID),
FOREIGN KEY (empID) REFERENCES slsemp (empID));
```

Now, I want to find employees that are in the west region that haven't made any sales. I figured I'd do this via a left outer join between the two tables then query the resulting table based off of a null tranx ID. I've got it most of the way there, here's my query:

```
SELECT e.empID, t.tranxID, e.RegionID
FROM slsemp e LEFT OUTER JOIN slstranx t ON e.empID=t.empID 
WHERE e.RegionID='WS'
```

My question is, how do I query based of the criteria of this resultant table. If I could do that, I simply would need a selection with criteria of slstranxID=null.

Answer (score 1):

You can use left join adding where  slstranx.empID is null

```
select distinct empID, empName
from slsemp
left join slstranx on slsemp.empID = slstranx.empID
where slsemp.RegionID = 'WS' 
and slstranx.empID is null
```

if the column from the table in left join  is null mean that don't match .. so don't have sales

Comment: I see. I got my result in a similar fashion, except I used slstranx.tranxID is null. The resulting tables are identical.

I guess final question is this: what's the difference between slstranx.<some_column> is null and  slstranx.<some_column>=null ?

Comment: @MadisonC.Brewer   the sintax some_column = null is wrong (sintax error)  in sql you must  use some_column is  null or you can override  rhe null value with eg: ifnull(some_column,'') = '' .. hope is clear  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: Odd, as the resulting query executed, it just resulted in an empty table. Oh, well. Now I know.

Comment: For what i know  The query i see at the bottom of your question should return  all the employes with or without sales ..   (not empty select)